# How to run a Google Docs add-on in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, clasp

There is a great Google Docs add-on [Code Blocks](https://github.com/alexwforsythe/code-blocks) that highlights blocks of code. Unfortunately, I cannot use it in my company's docs due to security/privacy concerns despite its privacy policy. Instead, I would like to fork it and run in our own Google App Script account. I have tried to create a new project and push the forked code to it without success. What would be step-by-step instructions to achieve a running add-on with that code?

Creating a new standalone App Script project, building and pushing the code to it results in the following error

```
  code: 400,
  errors:
   [ { message: 'A file with this name already exists in the current project: client/sidebar',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'badRequest' } ] }
└─ appsscript.json
└─ client/logo.svg.html
└─ client/sidebar.css.html
└─ client/sidebar.html
└─ client/sidebar.js
└─ dist/bundle.min.js.html
└─ dist/colors.js
└─ dist/constants.js
└─ dist/document.js
└─ dist/logo.svg.html
└─ dist/main.js
└─ dist/sidebar.css.html
└─ dist/sidebar.html
└─ dist/styles.html
└─ dist/util.js
└─ server/colors.js
└─ server/constants.js
└─ server/document.js
└─ server/main.js
└─ server/util.js
Pushed 20 files.
```

These files are not found in the project when opening it on the App Script webpage. It has just the default Code.gs placeholder file. I don't know where to even look to find the problem.

**Update:**

Thanks to Oleg in the comments, adding `.claspignore` allowed to push it to Apps Script but running a test in a Google Docs caused error

```
Exception: No HTML file named sidebar was found
```

All files are now in `dist/` folder so maybe it cannot find them because of this? Do I miss some config to put them correctly?

**Solution:**

Setting `rootDir` to `dist/` in `.clasp.json` solved the problem.

Comment: first of all, add all folders except those in `dist` to `.claspignore`, they are source files and should not be uploaded. Other than that, you are doing this the right way

Comment: Oh, I should have noticed that! :facepalm: Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :) I pushed a `node_modules` entire folder like this once, that was "fun"

Comment: I am doing it atm :( thought it's needed. Now clasp is dumping 130MB in stdout due to some error. Is there a way to ask clasp not to dump all content on error?

Comment: Oh I found why I had so many errors. I needed to specify rootDir when creating the project. It works now in my doc, thanks for your help!

Comment: One can also add `rootDir` to existing `.clasp.json`.

Comment: Andrei, nope, as far as I know, clasp dumps all the content when erroring during push, I experienced it a couple of times. `rootDir` is indeed a solution ( seems like the Add-on uses relative references to folders ). Glad you solved it!